# What is the difference between Rhino and Spidermonkey JavaScript engines?

Tags: javascript, rhino, spidermonkey

For the first time, I began learning Javascript, however on the start I stuck up with two possible options: Rhino and Spidermonkey. Could you please, tell me what is one, and what is another, so I can easily choose for myself the best option that suits my needs. If it makes easier for you, you can list advantages and disadvantages of both Javascript versions.

Comment: Are you trying to embed a JavaScript engine in your application...or are you just trying to learn JavaScript?

Comment: Both are JavaScript engines, not framework or JavaScript versions. But both support different version of JavaScript

Comment: I would like to embed a javascript engine in one of my applications.

Comment: @AndreasKöberle, I know I just wanted to have more tags, so that more people can see this, after all engine is some kind of initial framework right. Also, I didn't know for rhino and spidermonkey tags. ;) Thanks on your editing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It depends on what you're trying to do with JavaScript.  If your intent is just to learn the language then I recommend using a web browser such as Chrome or Firefox and using their built-in (or addon) JavaScript consoles.

As to your specific question about standalone JavaScript interpreters, here are some notes:

1. [Rhino](http://www.mozilla.org/rhino/) - implemented in Java, intended primarily for use as a scripting engine extension for the Java platform.  Includes an interactive command-line console, which will be helpful for learning.
2. [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey) - implemented in C/C++, intended for use as the JavaScript engine in Firefox.

See also:

1. [V8](http://code.google.com/p/v8/) - implemented in C++, designed primarily as the Chrome browser's JavaScript implementation; well suited for embedding.
2. [node.js](http://nodejs.org/) - a standalone, evented, asynchronous JavaScript environment, based on V8.
3. [Narwhal](https://github.com/tlrobinson/narwhal) - a CommonJS platform.
4. [Windows Script Host](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host) - includes a JScript interpreter (ECMAScript based, very similar to modern JavaScript).

Comment: Thank you for providing me with the links in which I can find documentation which will tell me more about the engines, and for the links of various JavaScript implementations.

Comment: i would add that for learning javascript the best two options are: a browser or node.js as both don't involve a build proccess _per se_, **but** if your learning _is_ about how to embbed js engines and use then as extensions to your learning language (like c++, java or c#) i then advice you that there be dragons, but building and thinkering with the one that suit's you is the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

Rhino is written in Java. SpiderMonkey is written in C/C++. I wouldn't go near either for the purposes of "learning JavaScript", for which a browser is probably more suitable.