# How to use (or avoid) Rhino Javascript in Thunderbird addon?

Tags: javascript, java, rhino, spidermonkey, thunderbird-addon

I'm running a bit JS code in a Thunderbird Extension (addon) that I'm developing. The code contains some basic Java classes. As soon as it hit a line like:

```
var s = java.lang.String ('');
```

It just stops working (freezes) without any error or any returns.

When I run the same Java code at my CLI It works fine.

I had a look around, and the way I understand it for now is, that these 'java.lang.String' things work only in the JS engine called Rhino. Mozilla also has another JS engine called 'spidermonkey'. Maybe anyone can answer one of these questions in ordr to help me out:

1. Which JS engine run in Thunderbird (for the addons)?
2. How can I write/test JS code that will run in TB, without deploying it into an addon all the time?
3. Why does the java.lang.String thing jsut freeze and stop instead of giving and error about an undefined symbol?
4. How can I make classes java.lang.String work in a TB extension?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though you have figured out the basic difference between Rhino & Spidermonkey, answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8898557/what-is-the-difference-between-rhino-and-spidermonkey-javascript-engines) contains more information about difference between various Javascript engines.

> Which JS engine run in Thunderbird (for the addons)?

JS engine run in Thunderbird is [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/search?page=3&q=thunderbird+spidermonkey&topic=api&topic=css&topic=html&topic=js&topic=apps&topic=webdev)

> How can I write/test JS code that will run in TB, without deploying it
>   into an addon all the time?

You can press Ctrl+Shift+j in Thunderbird to open the Error Console, where you can run JS in the text box with >> prefix.

> Why does the java.lang.String thing just freeze and stop instead of
>   giving and error about an undefined symbol?

IMHO its not hanging, it would have hit the exception block.

Running your code in Error Console of Thunderbird produced following error:

```
var str = new java.lang.String('hello');
ReferenceError: java is not defined [Learn More]
```

Running your code in Firefox which also uses SpiderMonkey produced following Exception:

```
var str = java.lang.String('Hello');
/*
Exception: ReferenceError: java is not defined
@Scratchpad/3:10:5
*/
```

> How can I make classes java.lang.String work in a TB extension?

One possible option is to use [XPCOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM), but that page itself warns about deprecation of XPCOM addons in the future.